# Mediaplayer doesn`t play sound

Tags: android, media-player

Mediaplayer should to play sound after onFinish countdownTimer, but it wouldn`t. After this code is only a Toast, which works fine. Before countdownTimer is dialog and onClick in my code snippet is from one of buttons of dialog.

```
btnYes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    dialogfeed.dismiss();
                    CountDownTimerfeed = new CountDownTimer(10000,1000) {

                        @Override
                        public void onTick(long millis) {


                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFinish() {
                         final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.melodyfeed);
                         mp.start();
                        }
                    };
```

Comment: Where is the Toast that work? Its not there?

Answer (score 0):

Create your `mediaPlayer` object out of your listener and only start it when user clicked on it.